# How to convert Json in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, neo4j, format

I'm creating an **API** with **Rails** and **Neo4j** and i have a query looks like this on my **model**

```
Neo4j::Session.query.match('(User)').where("lower(User.first_name) =~ '.*#{params[:name].downcase}.*'").return('User')
```

this query return **json** looks like

```
[
    {
        User: {
            user: {
                username: null,
                password: null,
                first_name: "ayman",
                last_name: "eldeeb",
                email: "ayman@gmail.com",
                phone: "44555",
                avatar: "url",
                birthdate: "1990-12-26"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Now, how to convert this **json** in **Ruby on Rails** to this below?

```
{
    users: [
        {
            id: 0,
            username: null,
            first_name: "adham",
            last_name: "eldeeb",
            phone: "010220234",
            email: null,
            avatar: "url",
            birthdate: null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That is not a valid JSON, but a Ruby hash literal.

Comment: @falsetru okay i know, but this is what returned to me!
if you have a better query, i will be grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but this can probably work..

```
require 'json' #this has to be in the top
.....
@data = JSON.parse(Neo4j::Session.query.match('(User)').where("lower(User.first_name) =~ '.*#{params[:name].downcase}.*'").return('User'))
```

Now @data will be a ruby variable parsed from the JSON output.. 
Now to get your desired output, maybe the following snippet can help

```
@desired_data = []
@data.each do |d|
  @desired_data << d[:User][:user] # this could be d["User"]["user"] if this dosen't work 
end
```

Comment: thank you it works fine but with d[:User] not d[:User][:user]

<3 :D

Comment: and i remove `JSON.parse` because it do an error with **neo4j**

Comment: Okay great.. It was just a hunch.. I could not figure out exact without actually playing with your code :)

Comment: Are you using Neo4j >= 2.0? If so, you should always use a label. Be aware that with a search like this, you won't be using an index, so it will be slow. The label should at least limit some of the results. What gem are you using for the Neo4j API? Looks like neo4j-core?